# xcode swift AnyObject to Swift convert

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

```
    let dataJSON = response .dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
    let decodedJson = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataJSON!, options: nil, error: nil) as NSDictionary
    println(decodedJson["UserId"])

    let BlockedValue = decodedJson["UserId"] as NSString
    NSLog("USER ID : %@",BlockedValue)
```

This code not work when i build code part;

First `println` work output : Optional(1269)
But second NSLog not work

How can i convert AnyObject to String i research on google this topic i found some code part but these are not work

I found this one is not worked

```
if let receiver = decodedJson["UserId"] as? NSString {

    self.receiver = receiver
}
```

Any idea help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `decodedJson["UserId"]` is an optional number.

One way to do it (you have to be sure decodedJson["UserId"] isnt' nil):

```
let number = decodedJson["UserId"]
if number != nil {
    let string = "\(number!)"
}
```

Or in condensed state:

```
if let number = decodedJson["UserId"] {
   let string = "\(number)"
}
```